# Where does kernel checks file's privilege before access?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, credentials, privileges

I try to understand how kernel check privilege of files, and which kernel files  are actually responsible for this task.

I haven't found documentation of this issue, except for
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/credentials.txt
Trying to search for credentials keyword in kernel I find that it is used in many files in kernel:

https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.8/ident/current_cred

The answer to the question seems to be related to `fsuid` credentials, But I didn't find how and where it is ued in kernel for file access.

So, **Where does the kernel do the actual task of testing if a file privilege is allowed for a process ?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I've found the code for file permissions check.

This is where are files being checked for permission:

In file **/fs/namei.c**:

```
/*
 * This does the basic permission checking
 */
static int acl_permission_check(struct inode *inode, int mask)
{
    unsigned int mode = inode->i_mode;

    if (likely(uid_eq(current_fsuid(), inode->i_uid)))
        mode >>= 6;
    else {
     ....
}
```